# JQuery - Filter nested list based on textbox input

Tags: jquery, html, list, filter, nested

I have a nested list of checkboxes which I need to filter them down based on textbox input compared to the label's value.  The list looks like this but a lot larger:

[image]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y9qqgjp5/

However, I'm having trouble with the nested part of this. As I have it now, if you go to search a user (2nd level item), the parent becomes hidden because it doesn't match and thus makes the children hidden, as well.  It works fine with filtering on a parent.

Here's the simplified structure I'm filtering on.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="filter" />
<span class="checkbox-list">
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Item1</label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Item2</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Item3</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Item4</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Item5</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Item6</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Item7</label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Item4</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Item8</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</span>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#filter').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.checkbox-list > ul > li > label').parent().show();
  } else {
    $('.checkbox-list > ul > li > label').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).parent().show(): $(this).parent().hide();
    });
  };

  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.checkbox-list > ul > li > ul > li > label').parent().show();
  } else {
    $('.checkbox-list > ul > li > > ul > li > label').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).parent().show(): $(this).parent().hide();
    });
  };
});
```

Any help is appreciated.  I can't wrap my head around the nested part of this.

Comment: So what did you want to happen? If I search for item2, it shows the parent and item2 itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```js
var labels = $('label');  // cache this for better performance

$('#filter').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  
  if (valThis == "") {
    labels.parent().show();          // show all lis
  } else {
    labels.each(function() {
      var label = $(this);                    // cache this
      var text = label.text().toLowerCase();
      if (text.indexOf(valThis) > -1) {
        label.parents('li').show()           // show all li parents up the ancestor tree
      } else {
       label.parent().hide();                // hide current li as it doesn't match
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="filter" />
<span class="checkbox-list">
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Item 1</label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Item 12</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Item3</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Item4</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Item5</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Item6</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Item7</label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Item4</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Item8</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</span>
```

Comment: This works for what I specified.  However, I did notice I don't like the functionality of one part: When it matches a parent, all of the children should show.  I'm not sure if that warrants another question or if it's an easy change... let me know.  I'll give it a shot myself, too.

Comment: That's probably a new question as it would be quite a big change, you wouldn't be able to use an each like above as you may hide children again after they are shown